# how to remove the cell from uitableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

Im trying to dynamically arranging table view when user select "type 3". It works when user select "type 3", "type 3-1" would be added in the tableview. However the program crashed when user select other than type3-1. I dont know how can I execute the "rows.remove(at:2)" before the override function is called. Any suggestion would appreciate!

```
class GuestViewController: UITableViewController {
var rows:[[[String:Any]]] = [[["type":RowType.DetailContent,
                               "subType":DCType.DCRightContent,
                               "name":CPFFields.CID,
                               "content":"9637"],                                  
                             ["type":RowType.DetailContent,
                              "subType":DCType.DCInput,
                              "name":CPFFields.VISIA]],

                             [["type":RowType.DetailTextView,
                               "CPFType":CPFFields.UV,
                               "title":CPFFields.preferenceTitle]],

                             [["type":RowType.DetailContent,
                               "subType":DCType.DCSelection,
                               "name":CPFFields.Phototherapy,
                               "title":CPFFields.anestheticTitle],
                              ["type":RowType.DetailTextView,
                               "CPFType":CPFFields.Phototherapy,
                               "title":CPFFields.preferenceTitle]],                                 
                             ]
var isNewGuestSelected : Bool = false

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  

    return rows[section].count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = rows[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]     

    let type = item["type"] as! RowType

    if type == RowType.DetailContent
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailNameCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailContentCell

        let cpfType = item["name"] as? CPFFields ?? .Customer
        cell.name.text = CPFFields.localizedString(from: cpfType)
        if let field = item["title"] as? CPFFields
        {
            cell.name.text = CPFFields.localizedString(from: field)
        }
        cell.moreSlectionLeftSpace = true

        var content:String? = ""
        cell.type = cpfType
        switch cpfType {
        case .CID:
            content = (profile?.birthDate.dateFromDateString?.stringForPaitentId ?? "") + (profile?.name ?? "")
        case .CT:
            content = ""
            if let profile = profile
            {
                content = CPFCustomerType.localizedString(from: profile.type)
                //New Guest
                if(content == CPFCustomerType.type1.rawValue){

                    rows[0].insert(["type":RowType.DetailContent,
                                    "subType":DCType.DCRightContent,
                                    "name":CPFFields.CID,
                                    "content":"9637"], at: 1)
                    isNewGuestSelected = true

                } else{
                    if isNewGuestSelected == true{
                        rows[0].remove(at: 1)
                        isNewGuestSelected = false
                    }
                }
            }


let subType = item["subType"] as! DCType
            cell.setcontentType(type: subType, content: content)
            return cell
    }

I expected not to see "rows[0][2]" after running "rows[0].remove(at:1)".
However the log is printing
    rows[0][0]
    rows[0][1]
    rows[0][2]        
    then 
    it crashed at "let item = rows[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]"
    because it is out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying your content while rendering, thus after `numberOfRows:inSection:` was called. Therefore the tableView is trying to access an element that no longer exists, since you removed it.

Your cycle:

```
→ number of rows 4
→ removed item, contents now has 3 items
→ cell for item 0
→ cell for item 1
→ cell for item 2
- cell for item 3 → crash
```

Consider replacing the logic you have here outside of the `cellForRow` method, and doing these operations before you reload your tableView.

You should use the `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath` strictly for dequeueing your cells and configuring them; not for modifying the underlying data store since funky things like you're experiencing now can happen.

If you provide a bit more context I can probably tell you where to place your code to fix this issue.

Comment: I have updated the example code, not sure if its enough. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is quite simple. I just added tableView.reloadData() after removing the array, and the UI can then be updated.

```
                if isNewGuestSelected == true{
                    rows[0].remove(at: 1)
                    isNewGuestSelected = false
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
```